# CSS hover effect. The border of the element is not covered

Tags: html, css

The first button is without the hover effect and it looks good, however in the second one with the hover effect, there is some small space not covered because of the border. Any idea what causes that?

[image]

Here's the code I wrote:

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  padding: 2em;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  background: #038C7E;
  padding: .85em 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  border-radius: .35em;
  border-width: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) transparent;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .2;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .3s;
}

.button:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="button-hover-shutterout.css">
  <title>Button Hover Shutterout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="button" href="#" role="button">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the button class add `overflow: hidden;` and in the button::before remove `border-radius: inherit;` like the following:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  background: #038C7E;
  padding: .85em 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  border-radius: .35em;
  border-width: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) transparent;
  overflow: hidden;/*Add This */
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .2;
  background: #000;
  /* border-radius: inherit; */
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .3s;
}
```